# i've a dataframe and i want to get values from a column called requester i'm getting an extra column along with requester column

Tags: python, pandas

in my data frame, I have a column called requester when I want to get data of requester column I'm getting another column data along with it, how to remove the extra column[image]

the data frame i've

and the code I'm trying here is

names = pd.DataFrame(report['Requester'])

and the output I'm getting is

[image]

I want to remove SLA resol column from daataframe.

Comment: You can apply: pd.DataFrame(report['Requester'].values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is first column is converted to `index`.

So possible solution is first add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default `index` and then for one column `DataFrame` add `[[]]` with column name:

```
report = report.reset_index()
names = report[['Requester']]
```

Another idea is create `DataFrame` with default index by `read_csv` or `read_excel` with `index=False`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, index=False)

df = pd.read_excel(file1, index=False)
```

---

Last if need write DataFrame without default index:

```
df.to_csv(file2, index=False)
df.to_excel(file12, index=False)
```